# WPF Create Area Consumption Calculator

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a project where I need to calculate how many "widgets" i can remove from an area defined by the user.

for example, if i have a piece of paper... 13in x 23in. How many business cards I print when the business card dimensions are 5in x 3in.

I need something like this...
http://www.copel.com.py/calculadora-de-corte.html

But the best I can do is use a WrapPanel, which does a good job, but if I need to rotate an object, it leaves me with blank space. meaning that wrap panel works by rows, and each row takes the space of the largest object. leaving wastage around the smaller ones.[image: See attached Image...]

How do you suggest I attack this problem?
C#, WPF, XAML.!

Comment: It's curious Windows 10 apps has a new panel called Relative Panel, but I do not know if will we available for WPF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel.aspx. But I think the graphic part it is not necessary for the calculus, it all about sizes and fit I do not know why you need that

Comment: using a panel simplifies life and positioning. the other way is doing it with canvas, but that requires me to store length and width, instead of x - y axis. this is why i want to see if there is some way i can hack it in. or else its a lot of manual coding.